# setState() reloads the entire page instead of re rendering only the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm trying to update a table in my component. Once I get the new value to the method, I concat this value to the array and call the setState method. But instead of re rendering only the component, it reloads the entire page and displays only the previous array values.

My code is like this:

```
export default class DataSrcInfoFields extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        dataSrcFieldList : this.props.fields,
    };

    this.handleNewRowSubmit = this.handleNewRowSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleRowRemoval = this.handleRowRemoval.bind(this);
}

handleNewRowSubmit(dataSrcFieldVal){
    const newList = this.state.dataSrcFieldList.concat(dataSrcFieldVal);

    this.setState({dataSrcFieldList: newList});
}

handleRowRemoval(field){

}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div>
                <DataSrcInfoFieldList dsFieldList={this.state.dataSrcFieldList} onFieldRemove={this.handleRowRemoval} />
            </div>
            <div>
                <DataSrcInfoAddField onNewFieldSubmit={this.handleNewRowSubmit} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

}
```

I have tried to print the new value (dataSrcFieldVal) inside the method so there is no issue with that. The newList array is also getting created which has the dataSrcFieldVal included in it. I've also binded the handleNewRowSubmit method in the constructor.

Can anyone please help me solve this issue and tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: this method is good. there is some other problem in your code.

Comment: Need more code. Where are you calling this from and your render menthod etc

Comment: Do not mutate the state. Try to copy the value by using Array.from(this.state.dataSrcFieldList). Also please share the other pieces of your code so that we can take a look at it and help :)

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your quick response. I've updated the code.

Comment: I have created a JSFiddle which is similar to your code and it works fine. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/ghoshnirmalya/xuL6v015/3/.